# How to use a custom hook defined in the host micro frontend to another micro frontend?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, micro-frontend

- I'm using next js
  in host app my useLoader hook is exist.
  here is the code

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function useLoader(): { loading: boolean } {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const requestInspector = axios.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        setLoading(true);
        return config;
      },
      (error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
    const responseInspector = axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        return response;
      },
      (error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
    return () => {
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(requestInspector);
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(responseInspector);
    };
  }, []);
  return { loading };
}

export default useLoader;
```

and here is my host next.config file

```
const { NextFederationPlugin } = require("@module-federation/nextjs-mf");
const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = withImages({
  staticPageGenerationTimeout: 1000,
  output: "standalone",
  images: { unoptimized: true },
  webpack(config, options) {
    const { isServer } = options;
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: "host",
          remotes: {
            patientCommunication: `patientCommunication@${
              process.env.APP_PATIENT_COMMUNICATION
            }/_next/static/${isServer ? "ssr" : "chunks"}/remoteEntry.js`,
          },
          exposes: {
            "./useLoader": "./src/hooks/useLoader",
            "./Back": "./src/components/Back",
          },
          filename: "static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",
        })
      );
    }

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(ts)x?$/, // Just `tsx?` file only
      use: [
        {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            experimentalWatchApi: true,
            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
});
```

I'm trying to use this in another micro frontend

here is the next.config file for my micro-frontend

```
const { NextFederationPlugin } = require("@module-federation/nextjs-mf");
const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = withImages({
  staticPageGenerationTimeout: 1000,
  output: "standalone",
  images: { unoptimized: true },
  webpack(config, options) {
    const { isServer } = options;
    if (!isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: "patientCommunication",
          filename: "static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",
          exposes: {
            "./patientCommunication": "./src/pages/index.tsx",
            "./abc": "./src/pages/rohit.tsx",
          },
          remotes: {
            host: `host@${process.env.APP_HOST}/_next/static/${
              isServer ? "ssr" : "chunks"
            }/remoteEntry.js`,
          },
        })
      );
    }
    return config;
  },
});
```

But when i use this useLoader of host in my component like this

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import dynamic, { Loader } from "next/dynamic";
const CustomHook = dynamic(() => import('host/useLoader').then((module) => module.default)
);

function Test() {
  const { loading } = CustomHook();
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => setData(json));
    };
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>hello</p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

It throws module not found error. I wonder what is the mistake. Please guide me where i'm doing mistake